# How do you use OAuth 1 to sign a POST request with binary data?

Tags: oauth

I have an api endpoint to allow file uploads, but I want to authenticate the user via OAuth. The problem is that the post data is binary and doesnt consist of a key/value pair like form data. Therefore, how do you include it in the SignatureBaseString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Signature Base String you only need to include parameters with a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (see [OAuth Core 1.0a section 9.1.1](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#anchor13)).

The file upload will be of content type `multipart/form-data` so you don't need to include it in your Signature Base String.